# Loading large datasets from HDF5 file with python

Tags: python, scipy, h5py

I have some dataset files with ~20 million data points in it (~32 GB size).
Is there a good way to fast load the data? I want to load the data to create two hdf5 files for training a neural network.

Edit:
Currently, I load the data with

```
for File in FilesToLoad
     DataFile = h5py.File(File , "r")
     Label = list(DataFile.get("Label"))

for Item in Label:
    if(not(Item in ClassLabels)):
          ClassLabels.append(Item)
```

The program takes a long time at "Label = list(...)". The second for-loop is to create a list of unique labels from all of my labels, so I can use a Labelencoder to encode them. This takes a long time too.
Is there a more efficient way to do pick the unique values out of a large list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for? How do you currently load the file?

Comment: I´ve updated the problem description. Hope the problem should be more clear now.

Comment: Ok, so the question is quite a bit different now. What is `ClassLabels`?

Comment: `ClassLabels` is a list with the unique labels from the `Labels`-list.
`Labels` contain 20 million labels (different unknown states) and `ClassLabels` contain each unique label. I use the list `ClassLabels` for my label encoder to get  my output vectors for my neural network.

Comment: Can you convert that to a set?

Comment: I´ve tried it with a set first, but it takes a long time too.
Is there any way to use multiple cores for loading the data?

Comment: Simply loading the data in a numpy array data=DataFile["Label"].copy() and using ClassLabels=np.unique(data) doesn't do the job?